# How can I view boot order from command prompt? Also, what place should an auxiliary drive be in?

Tags: command-line, boot, ssd

I'm buying a second SSD for my Lenovo P50; its gonna be for games, videos, pictures, etc. The OS and certain programs will still be on the SSD that it came with. I wanna know what place in the boot order it should be in. Also, how can I just view, not change, the boot order, from command prompt? I tried using the screenshot button from the BIOS but it didn't work.

My computer is on Windows 10 Home.

Comment: you should get a computer to experiment with and your question should be how do you go to the BIOS, and go there.. And then you need to find the place in the BIOS where boot order is mentioned.. and if you can't find it then include a pic of your BIOS, take the pic with your phone. Somebody might recognize it as their BIOS and tell you or they may know anyway from having fiddled around.. You should try pressing ENTER in places.. see if it goes to another screen. And don't fear changing it, you can always change it back. And nowadays it's technically called a UEFII not BIOS

Comment: nobody generally tries to view boot order from the command prompt.. it's a very very technical question, i'm not sure it's possible but it might be.

Comment: maybe there is a way to dump memory.. win7 64bit doesn't have debug.. win7 32bit does.. but debug aside. This WMIC command wmic bios get /format:list   shows some BIOS or UEFI info but not your settings, it doesn't show the boot order... so i'm not sure.. great question though

Comment: Adding a new disk for data does not require any changes to the boot order.

Comment: I'm going to have to agree with both comments, **1.** use the device manufacturer WMIC hook commands to see BIOS level configuration such as boot order but the example syntax I see provided is not sufficient so you'd need to do some homework on the class, path, namespace, etc. of what you need to call but PowerShell command line querying WMI objects may be easier. Consider just checking BIOS for the configuration. UEFI is not BIOS and is an extension of BIOS so you still have BIOS nowadays too............... **2.** Agree... You should not need to change boot order to add a new disk for data.

Comment: This may have some helpful pointers for what I was talking about with the device manufacture's hook into the WMI BIOS... https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/skl_deploy_01.pdf

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you do not need to change any boot order sequences.  In the case of a desktop, you just need to make sure your boot drive is in the [lowest numbered SATA port](https://www.alphr.com/features/378925/how-to-install-an-ssd).

As you have a laptop, not all laptops can hold a second SSD drive.  Luckily for you, there is the option, but it depends on what you want to do.  [There is only 1x 2.5" drive slot and there are 2 slots for m2 SSD drives](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-P-and-W-Series-Mobile/P50-Hard-disk-drive-cable/td-p/2244743).

However, there is a way to [convert the 2x m2 slots into a single 2.5" drive slot](https://www.ok1.de/thinkpad/HMM/p50_hmm_en_sp40j71944.pdf) (see page 64).  Whichever way you choose, as long as the original drive stays where it is, there is no need to change your boot sequence.